# Re-using a radiobutton in Android

Tags: android

Th question: Can I re-use RadioButton objects over and over again in an child activity?

I have a parent activity and a child activity.  In the child activity, I have a large number of radio button displayed in a UI.  In order to provide databinding from the parent down to the child, I have created a class (below) which contains a collection of RadioButtons.  To populate the child activity, I pass a reference to this class down to the child which then groups the radioButtons into RadioGroups and displays them.  I do this because the checked status of each button is now automatically available in the parent class, without the need to transfer any data through bundles.

```
public class GeneralAttribute{
    Activity  mThis;
    public class Gender {         // Mutually exclusive members
        String      categoryDesc  = "Gender of user";
        RadioButton isUnspecified = initRadioButton("Unspecified", true);
        RadioButton isMale        = initRadioButton("Male"       , false);
        RadioButton isFemale      = initRadioButton("Female"     , false);
    } ;
    <....more subclasses....>
    RadioButton initRadioButton(String str, Boolean b) {   // Factory
        float cLayoutWeight = 0.5f;
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(mThis);
        rb.setText   (str);
        rb.setChecked(b);
        rb.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, cLayoutWeight));
        return rb;
    }
    GeneralAttribute(Activity localThis){ // Constructor
        mThis = localThis;
        gender     = new Gender();
        handedness = new Handedness();
        location   = new Location();
    }
}
```

In the parent activity i have:

```
public class Parent(...)

   public GeneralAttribute mGeneralAttribute;              // Member class of RadioButtons
   public static SPIGestureLoggerActivity TopLevelActivity;// Reference to the parent activity

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       TopLevelActivity = this;                            // Assign this to the reference
       mGeneralAttribute = new GeneralAttribute(this);     // Initialize the class of RBs
       startActivity(child);                               // Start the child
```

In the child activity i have this:

```
    radiogroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    radiogroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    radiogroup.addView(Parent.TopLevelActivity.mGeneralAttribute.gender.isUnspecified);
    radiogroup.addView(Parent.TopLevelActivity.mGeneralAttribute.gender.isMale);
    radiogroup.addView(Parent.TopLevelActivity.mGeneralAttribute.gender.isFemale);
    Parent.TopLevelActivity.mGeneralAttribute.gender.isUnspecified.setChecked(true);
    mLinearLayout.addView(radiogroup);
```

This works fine....the first time the child activity is displayed.  The second time it is displayed I get an exception.
In summary, here is the chain of events:

- create the class of RadioButtons,
- pass them to the child,
- add them to a new RadioGroup
- collect user choices
- finish the child acitivty (which should destroy the RadioGroups)
- use the data in the parent,
- start the child activity again,
- attempt to add the RadioButtons to new RadioGroups...
  ...Exception.

I can avoid this problem, if I null the class and reconstruct it.  However, I would like to re-show the choices made from the first viewing with the second viewing.

Ideas:

- Are the radioButtons saving pointers to the non-existant RadioGroups from the first viewing?
- Is there a way to re-assign the view parent on each radio button in the class?

P.S. You may ask why I'm not using XML.  For one, I will have 100+ of these radio buttons and I think it will be too painful to manage through XML.  For another, I just like working programmatically on these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you remove all the radiobuttons from the all radiogroups. Basically your right the radiobuttons are saving pointers to the non-existant raidogroups and no there isn't isn't a way to reassigned without calling removeAllViews on all the radiogroups. The best place to do that will be the onDestroy if your sure thats being called.

Comment: Great!  I was searching for a method like clear() or setParent().   I didn't think of remove.  I'll try it now.

Comment: Awesome.  That fixed it!  And you've just validated a half days worth of work! I was afraid that I would have to dump this and rebuild it.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, is this technique of passing a view object down to a child class all that unusual?  I seems strange to me, but it fit my needs.

Comment: I haven't used this before (i think) but it seems like its reduced a good amount of boiler plate code (no onSwitches, always having the current values and faster loading of the views since they are made). So i say its a a good use of it. My one concern would be memory depending on what else your app is doing all those radiobuttons being load into memory could come back to get you. Since they are much heavier than a class with currentValue and possible values in strings only.